# Python: What is a good format for long regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, formatting

When using the re module in python, what is a good way to format long regular expressions to make them more readable?

For example, the format I used is:

```
regex = re.compile(r"\s*("
                        "\d+"                       
                        "\".*\""                    
                        "|'.'"                      
                        "|[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_\d]*"                    
                        ")")
```

Are there any suggestions for how I could have improved this for readability?

Comment: [re.X](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.X)

Comment: @ stribizhev  Thanks.  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Use a good regex formatting app like this [Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)